# tinydb: how to update a document with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, tinydb

Hi I would like to update some documents that match a query. So for each document I would like to update the field `'parent_id'` if and only if this document have an ID `greater then` i.e. 6

```
        for result in results:
            db.update(set('parent_id', current_element_id), 
                      result.get('id') > current_element_id )
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 569, in <module>
    convertxml=parse(xmlfile, force_list=('interface',))
  File "debug.py", line 537, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
  File "..\Modules\pyexpat.c", line 468, in EndElement
  File "debug.py", line 411, in endElement
    db.update(set('parent_id', current_element_id), result.get('id') > current_element_id )
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tinydb\database.py", line 477, in update
    cond, doc_ids
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tinydb\database.py", line 319, in process_elements
    if cond(data[doc_id]):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

example of document that should be update:

```
...,
{'URI': 'http://www.john-doe/',
 'abbr': 'IDD',
 'affiliation': 'USA',
 'closed': False,
 'created': '2018-06-01 22:49:02.927347',
 'element': 'distrbtr',
 'id': 7,
 'parent_id': None
 },...
```

In the [documentation](http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#updating-data) of **tinydb** I see that I can use **set**. Otherwise if I don't use **Set** it will update **all** the document `db.update(dict)` which I don't want to.

Comment: `set('parent_id', current_element_id)` is illegal in Python. Did you redefine the built-in `set` function somewhere in your program?

Comment: Thanks @DyZ for your comment. I am not sure why do they implement a `set` into TinyDB

Answer (score 4):

Using the Docs using `write_back` to [replace](http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#replacing-data) part of a document is better

```
>>> docs = db.search(User.name == 'John')
[{name: 'John', age: 12}, {name: 'John', age: 44}]
>>> for doc in docs:
...     doc['name'] = 'Jane'
>>> db.write_back(docs)  # Will update the documents we retrieved
>>> docs = db.search(User.name == 'John')
[]
>>> docs = db.search(User.name == 'Jane')
[{name: 'Jane', age: 12}, {name: 'Jane', age: 44}]
```

implementing it to my situation

```
for result in results:
    if result['parent_id'] != None:
        result['parent_id']  = current_element_id
db.write_back(results)
```

Comment: `write_back` has been removed in 4.0 (for no reason).